# AngularJS: one service several modules

Tags: angularjs, service, module

This is a question about AngularJS modules and services, and how to define them.

1. An app can be composed of multiple modules
2. A service allows commonly-used code to be factored out and used by multiple modules
3. A service is (commonly) defined with:
   angular.module('module1').factory('serviceA', function() { ... } );

If the above are all true, then why does the definition of serviceA include a reference to module1? Shouldn't it be ignorant of any modules that want to use it?

If I was building a module2 and I referenced serviceA.js in order to access the above service, it would tell me that module1 is not defined.

I guess my question is how do I create a set of independent modules and have them all access a global service? In all the examples I've seen the service is tightly-coupled to a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

The factory() method is a method on module, so you need a module instance to be able to call it. Essentially, that statement says that you want that factory to be defined on that specific module.

If you need module1 in something used in module2, then module2 should declare a dependency on module1:

```
angular.module('module2', ['module1']);
```

One thing that writing unit tests will teach you really quickly is that the more places something is used, the *more* important it is to put it in a module. If you try to treat it as "global" because it's used in a lot of places, that means you have to bootstrap the entire app just to use those services that are basically used everywhere.